# undefined method `nearest_larger' for main:Object

Tags: ruby

in order to prepare for a challenge, I'm trying to solve a bunch of 'easy' questions on ruby. However, they are not very easy for me :P.

The problem states -- >

```
# Write a function, `nearest_larger(arr, i)` which takes an array and an
# index.  The function should return another index, `j`: this should
# satisfy:
#
# (a) `arr[i] < arr[j]`, AND
# (b) there is no `j2` closer to `i` than `j` where `arr[i] < arr[j]`.
#
```

I don't want to look at the answer year, so have poured what I know so far into writing the following code --

```
def nearest_larger(arr, i)
  j = 0
  k = i+1 
  larger_hash = {}

    while j < i 
        larger_hash[arr[j]] = j if arr[i] < arr[j]
        j +=1
    end

    while k < (arr.count - 1) do 
        larger_hash[arr[k]] = k if arr[i] < arr[k]
        k+=1
    end

    max_value = larger_hash.keys.max 


end

nearest_larger([3, 5, 6, 14, 20, 18], 2)
```

I'm pretty sure there will be some beautiful and easy way to answer this question, but alas, I don't know why my solution is spitting out a NoMethodError.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't get a `NoMethodError` but some other errors instead. For example, addressing value in a hash like this `larger_hash{arr[j]}` is incorrect. You have to use square brackets. Then you have "Can't compare nil with fixnum error"

Comment: Whop, fixed that, now I'm where you're at, can't compare nil with fixnum. Thanks for the help Sergio

Comment: You should also change the loop to `for j in ((i+1)..(arr.count-1)) do`

Comment: Just updated the question with the suggestions given. This time no error, but when I run it I get no return value.

Comment: You should avoid editing the question to change its meaning. Open a new question once the first problem is fixed otherwise the questions/answers become difficult to follow for others who might find and hope to resolve a similar problem. Or if you are getting good interaction with other users, it may be better to take that to chat (particularly if it is very specific to what you are doing and not so instructive to others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem is a syntax error in your method which causes it not to be defined, so when you try to call it later it is not found.

The cause of the syntax error is the use of braces `{}` instead of brackets `[]` to access keys inside a hash.

Do not be confused by `perl` in this respect.

**Accessing a hash value is different**

```
in perl: some_hash{a_key}
in ruby: some_hash[a_key]
```

This may seem strange, since both use braces for hash literals:

**Assigning an empty hash literal is the same**

```
in perl: some_hash = {}
in ruby: some_hash = {}
```

Comment: Hey Fd, thanks for this, fixed :). I think I made another mistake though, I'm actually calling the largest key value at the end, but I want to call the closest key value to i. Do you know how I would write that?

Comment: You could change the key to be the absolute distance from i, then get the minimum one. The associated value would then be the index of (one of) the closest candidates.

Comment: You are doing more work than necessary, however, by storing all greater values in a hash. You could just iterate out from i and find the first larger value then stop. You could do this just by adding an extra condition on each while loop, combined with keying on the abs distance from i (alternatively, you could just dispense with the hash, but then you might need more long-winded code to decide what to return.)

Comment: Actually I have a pretty short solution now without hashes required, and with better theoretical run time. Let me know if you want any more hints.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered above.  You might wish to consider alternative ways of writing your method that make better use of Ruby's expressiveness, such as what I have suggested below.  As this does not answer your question, I considered moving it to a comment above, but comments are not really intended for more than a single line of code, and multiple lines of code cannot be formatted properly in a comment.

```
def nearest_larger(arr, i)
  # maybe check for i.abs >= arr.size
  a = arr.each_with_index.sort.map {|v , idx| v}
  j = a.index(arr[i])
  return arr.index(a[j+1]) if j+1 < arr.size
  nil    
end
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Thank you for the advice.  After reading your comment I tried to convert my answer to a comment, as you suggested, but ran into code formatting problems.  I edited my answer to explain the reason for my answer.